# Device name of a Bluetooth device in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth

Can i get the name of an connected Bluetooth device on the iPad in my application developed in Xcode ? is this possible ? and how do you do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial here:

http://www.touchthatfruit.com/ios-bluetooth-development-tutorial-using-game

And some information here:

[Bluetooth Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1)